# How can I change the bar color of a kendo sparkline for Angular 2+

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

I have a kendo sparkline, bullet graph for angular 2.  The default color of the bar is orange, but I need to change the color.  I have looked at the reference on the progress site and it appears that there is a [color property](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/charts/api/Series/#toc-color) for the value axis, but when I try and change this the bar disappears.

html

```
    <kendo-sparkline [data]="Data" type="bullet" [valueAxis]="bulletValueAxis">
    </kendo-sparkline>
```

.ts file - value axis

```
        this.bulletValueAxis = {
        min: 0,
        max: 30,
        color: 'purple',
        background: 'grey',
        // title: { text: 'test' },
        type: 'numeric',
        plotBands: [{
            from: 0, to: this.config.min, color: 'yellow', opacity: 0.3
        }, {
            from: this.config.min, to: this.config.max, color: '#008b00', opacity: 0.3
        }, {
            from: this.config.max, to: this.config.max + 5, color: '#ff0000', opacity: 0.3
        }]
    };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The color property is part of the [series](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/charts/api/Series/#toc-series) or seriesDefaults configuration (as opposed to the valueAxis one), e.g.:

```
<kendo-sparkline [data]="bulletData" type="bullet" [seriesDefaults]="{color: 'purple'}" [valueAxis]="bulletValueAxis">
```

[EXAMPLE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mj4rca?file=app/app.component.ts)